# Free Trier eligibility of AWS account and AWS Organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I recently found out through aws support that if your Organization's Root account is not within the free tier, then the attached account to the root account is also not eligible for free-tier unless it is stand-alone(the attached account are a new account and eligible for free tier).

Now my query is if I create a new account then make it an Organization's Root account and associate account eligible for free tier to the Organization. Will I be eligible for AWS free tier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AWS documentation the below is stated:

> If your company creates your AWS account through AWS Organizations, AWS Free Tier eligibility for all member accounts begins on the day that the master account of the organization is created.

This means that if your Organization master account was created further than 12 months ago there will be no free tier access. The usage itself is distributed across the entire Organization.

> To calculate the Organization’s use of AWS Services under any Offers, we will aggregate the usage across all accounts in the Organization.

If any stand alone accounts have already used their free tier, when the account is attached to the Organization the entire Organization will no longer have free-tier.